# ruby :- Unable to click on button using Watir click

Tags: ruby, watir

I have been trying to click on login button of a web application. But somehow get connection refused error for .click method. Sharing the code and the output. Can anyone please help in resolving the issue /pointing out the mistake?

[image: the Element details]

[image: Code]

[image: output]

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please, post your text as (formatted) text, not as an image.

Comment: Maybe your firewall or A/V is blocking that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. Apologies as the images were not available. I was getting the below error while I was trying to click on the login button of a web application.
Error ==
"Failed to open a TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5555(No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.- connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 5555) (Error::ECONNREFUSED)

However, when I downgraded the existing IEdriver version to 2.52.0.0 this problem got resolved and was able to click on the login button.

Comment: Don't use IE Driver ever when you tend to automate IE, please prefer watir-classic that would do the wonderful Job.